# Make foreach array values visible outside loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm a newbie in PHP and want to ask something on how all of values of array visible outside `foreach` loop. My code goes this:

```
$reference = $_POST['ref'];
$userDoc = $_POST['userDoc'];

$doc = array_filter($userDoc);
$ref = array_filter($reference);

foreach($doc as $a=> $value){
    $docs = $doc[$a];
    $refe = $ref[$a];
    echo $docs . $refe; // Result: all values in the array
}
echo $docs . $refe; // Result: only the last value in array
```

The result inside the loop is **a1b2c3**. 
 
While outside the loop is **c3** only.

Note that **a1b2c3** value are based on input value given by the user. I want to make all values visible for updating 1 row in the database.
Thank you in advanced.

Comment: you have to figure out what loops are used for first.. you can't make them output all the values outside the loops it just stays at the last value before the loop ends.

Comment: How exactly do you want to use array values to update the database?

Comment: I'm sorry, I actually want to update the database using the value of array $docs and $refe. I'd go to echo for testing what values may appear. Thank you for all responses, I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($doc as $a=> $value){
$docs = $doc[$a];
$refe = $ref[$a];
echo $docs . $refe; //echo all values in the array
}
```

Here, each time you are redeclaring the `$docs` and `$refe`. You need to append the new value to the existing variable using dot operator like :

```
foreach($doc as $a=> $value){
 $docs.=$doc[$a];
 $refe.=$ref[$a];
}
echo $docs. $refe;
```

Comment: This will print:
a1ab12abc123

Comment: I don't want to merge them, I want to separate the values of $doc and $ref to update the existing value in the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a string looking like `a1b2c3`, you can do it so:

```
foreach($doc as $a => $value){
    $output .= $doc[$a] . $ref[$a]
}
echo $output; //echo outside of the loop
```